# Changing border-color on selection

Tags: css, webkit, mozilla, pseudo-element

I'm trying to modify the default selection styles by using the `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` pseudoelements. I've successfully changed the selection color and background with these two rules:

```
::-moz-selection{ background: #444; color:#fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background:#444; color:#fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

However, I also need to change the `border-color` to white on selection for links. I'm trying to accomplish this with this CSS:

```
a::-moz-selection { border-color:#FFF;}
a::selection {border-color:#FFF; }
```

Even when I add an `!important` override, Safari won't style the border color.

What am I missing? Why can't I change a link's `border-color` on selection?

Comment: Is it possible you mean focus or active instead of selection?

Comment: No, I definitely mean selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define `border` styles for text selections.

Try defining an `outline` instead (it was going to be one of the allowed properties as stated in the [old spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#UIfragments) and the [SitePoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-selection)):

```
a::-moz-selection { outline: 1px solid #fff; }
a::selection { outline: 1px solid #fff; }
```

If that doesn't work, then I'm afraid the browser just doesn't support outlines on `::selection`.

Remember that [`::selection` has been move out of the Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selection), with the rest of CSS level 3 still being a draft, so you can't rely on browsers implementing it correctly/completely just yet.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @daysrunaway: About a decade ago while CSS3 was in very, very early draft stages and `::selection` was still in definition, [this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#UIfragments) didn't state border as one of the properties you can use. Implementing UAs still follow the same rules today though.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I'll have to stick to `text-decoration:underline;` instead.

Comment: @daysrunaway: Actually, see if you can define an outline instead (with my edit).