# How to style an input's border color on selection?

Tags: css, input, colors, border, pseudo-class

My Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/BeErL

I found this question and the answerer is saying that selection was deprecated / removed?
[Changing border-color on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405854/changing-border-color-on-selection)

Anyways I'm trying to get keep the border/outline size to 2 pixels on selection. However when the input field is selected the 2px border goes away (or maybe border or outline goes away?)

Also I want to make sure that when the input is selected the border color changes to the darker #b5b5b5.

HTML

```
<div id="login-form">

  <input type="username" id="login-username" name="username" value="username">
  <input type="password" id="login-password" name="password" value="password">

  <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>

  <button type="button">login</button>

</div>
```

CSS

```
input {
  margin: 0 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 42px;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  color: #b1b3b3;
  border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  outline: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input::selection {
  /* Safari */
  outline: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
  border: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
}
input::-moz-selection {
  /* Firefox */
  outline: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
  border: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
}

button {
  margin: 0 35px 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 $orange_color, 15%;
  background: $orange_color;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 darken($orange_color, 15%);
  background: lighten($orange_color, 5%);
}
```

Comment: try the :focus pseudo class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `input:focus` instead of `input::selection`.

This is documented in the [CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) specification.